# how to add slideDown() feature to card-body in bootstrap 4 using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, express

This is my html code for the card:

```
<div class="row">
        <% pro.forEach(function(pros){ %>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4">
            <div class="card mb-4 shadow ">
                <img class="card-img-top " src="<%= pros.image %>">
                <div class="card-body p-2 m-3">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><%= pros.name %></h5>
                    <p class="card-text my-0"><%= pros.description %></p>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <% }) %>
    </div>
```

I want to add a slide down feature to `card-body` when the mouse is hovering over `card-img-top`.
I'm trying to use jQuery but I can't get it working. Her is my attempt with jQuery code:

```
<script>
$(".card-img-top").click(function() {
  $(".card-body").slideUp();
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you share the eample URL , how would you like your output be like.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that there are many cards with `card-body` class as you are running loop to create card so, you need to target the one where you are clicking. Also, `slideup()` is for material UI. Here is one solution to your problem which you can customize as per your need.

```
.card-body {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    max-height: 500px; /* approximate max height  choose whatever suits you*/
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: .5s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
}
.card-body.closed {
    max-height: 0;
}

$(document).on("click", ".card-img-top" , function() {
    $('.card-body').removeClass('closed');
    $(this).closest('.card-body').addClass('closed');
});
```

Comment: Hey, there is nothing like .slideUp() in bootstrap 4 but it's there in Material UI. However, I have developed a custom solution to your problem and I am modifying my solution with it. Let me know if this is what you are looking for.